# Automate update database

Tags: django, django-models

i have application for dailyhours for work,i just looking around about specific hour will be run script to check database if some value are None will be add value to database.

So my question is i need do this with some script with rest api or maybe django-celery will be okay for that ?
example:

```
start:8:00
end:12:00
daily:4:00
```

but sometimes if you forget close work you need change value for some workers in PA so i wanna create script which will be do it automate everyday if value are None

Comment: [Answered a relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70475633/12914274) lately, might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need some background mechanics. I suggest two approaches

- Django Celery. You can run [periodic tasks](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#entries) with Celery.
- Manually set up crontab. It seems easier option for your task. You can create [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-management-commands/)  `check_db.py` and run it via crontab like this `0 8,12,16 * * * python3 /path/to/your/app/manage.py  check_db`